# How to use VLC as a live Streaming server?

Tags: android, api, vlc, http-live-streaming, rtmps

I'm working on android app which can stream video to Facebook via compiled VLC-library. After recent changes in Facebook policy https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/v2/2019/04/16/live-video-uploads-rtmps/ VLC stopped to stream video. There is message in the log:

> standard stream out: no suitable sout access module for
>   'rtmp/flv://rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/xxxxxxxxx.....'

Can anyone help me to understand - what should be done to re-enable streaming? My guess was to compile VLC with --enable-gnutls flag, but I'm not sure how to do this with current VLC sources

Comment: You can use an alternative which is [this](https://letzgro.net/blog/how-to-use-vlc-as-a-live-streaming-server/) using VideoLAN Network Stream.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of VLC on Android are you using?
Could you provide a longer version of the logs?

According to this issue: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android/issues/158
By setting the flag `--enable-sout` in `compile-libvlc.sh` it should maybe start working

Answer (score 0):

Direct use of **Network Stream** is one option you can try from [here](https://letzgro.net/blog/how-to-use-vlc-as-a-live-streaming-server/)

Overview of the `VideoLAN` streaming solution - [image]

[Documentation](https://www.videolan.org/doc)

Related to your doubt on stream video to  Facebook [Preset with rtmp](https://mxlight.co.uk/stream-preset-help---rtmp.html)

Comment: These are the ways you can directly do VLC live streaming.